# Azure releasing complications

Tags: azure, release-management

We are considering to build a webapplication and rely on Azure. The main idea behind this application is that users are able to work together on specific tasks in the cloud. I'd love to go for the concept of instant releasing where users are not bothered with downtime but I have no idea how I can achieve this (if possible at all). Lets say 10.000 users are currently working on this webapplication, and I release software with database updates.

- What happens when I publish a new release of my software into Azure?
- What will happen to the brilliant work in progress of my poor users?
- Should I bring the site down first before I publish a new release?
- Can I "just release" and let users enjoy the "new" world as soon as they request a new page?

I am surprised that I can't find any information about releasing strategies in Azure, am I looking in the wrong places?

Comment: Did you consider a cluster of servers? One server alone won't probably fitting your needs, since you had to reload new components at runtime which is the actual problem, if i understand you right. Using a cluster would allow you to route the users to one instance, while the other instance can be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

I suggest you create one of the visual stdio template applications and take a look at the "staging" and "production" environments located directly when you click your azure site in portal manager.

Say for example the users work on the "production" environment which is connected to Sqlserver1. You publish your new release to "staging" which is also connected to Sqlserver1. Then you just switch the two using the swap and staging becomes the "production" environment.

I'm not sure what happens to their work if they have something stored in sessions or server caches. Guess they will be lost. But client side stuff will work seamlessly.

"Should I bring the site down first before I publish a new release?"
I would bring up a warning (if the users work conissts of session stuff and so forth) saying brief downtime in 5 minutes and then after the swith telling everyone it is over.

Comment: thanks man that's exactly what i was looking for. the term "staging" with azure gives me hits on google that can help me further :). /bows thx again!

Answer (score 3):

Windows Azure is a great platform with many different features which can simplify lots of software management tasks. However, bear in mind that no matter how great platform you use,  your application depends on proper system architecture and code quality - well written application will work perfectly fine; poorly written application will fail. So do not expect that Azure will solve all your issues (but it may help with many).

```
What happens when I publish a new release of my software into Azure?
```

Windows Azure Cloud Services has a concept of Production and Staging deployments. New code deployment goes to staging first. Then you can do a quick QA over there (sometimes "warm up" the application to make sure it has all caches populated - but that depends on application design) and perform "Swap" - your staging deployment becomes production and production deployment becomes staging. That gives you ability to perform "rollback" in case of any issues with the new code. Swap operation is relatively fast as it is mostly internal DNS switch.

```
What will happen to the brilliant work in progress of my poor users?
```

It is always good idea to perform code deployments during the lowest site load (night time). Sometimes it is not possible e.g. if your application is used by global organization. Then you should use "the lowest" activity time.

In order to protect users you could implement solutions such as "*automatic draft save*" which happens every X minutes. But if your application is designed to work with cloud systems, users should not see any functionality failure during new code release.

```
Should I bring the site down first before I publish a new release?
```

That depends on architecture of your application. If the application is very well designed then you should not need to do that. Windows Azure application I work with has new code release once a month and we never had to bring the site down since the beginning (for last two years).

I hope that will give you better understanding of Azure Cloud Services.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks a lot! I guess most things become "clear" when you really start developing and releasing but this definitely helps in taking away some uncertainties and maybe in some cases confirming the vague assumptions in my mind. In any case thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out!